# Material UI: Give TableBody a max height and make it vertically scrollable

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Using Material UI, I want the TableBody of my Table to have a max height of 500px. If there are any rows that cannot fit within the height of the TableBody then the TableBody should vertically scroll while the TableHead locks in place (frozen).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';

const data = ["1", "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"];

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow style={{ 'backgroundColor': '#f5f5f5', "height": '35px' }}>
              <TableCell>Column 1</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Column 2</TableCell>
              <TableCell></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data.map(n => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={n}>
                  <TableCell>{n}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{n}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/y03vmkkkqj

How can this be done in Material UI?

Please fork from my example and provide link to a working solution.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `stickyHeader` prop in `Table` component and give `maxHeight` to `TableContainer`.

```
<TableContainer style={{ maxHeight: 150 }}>
  <Table stickyHeader>
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow style={{ 'backgroundColor': '#f5f5f5', "height": '35px' }}>
        <TableCell>Column 1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Column 2</TableCell>
        <TableCell></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      {data.map(n => {
        return (
          <TableRow key={n}>
            <TableCell>{n}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{n}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      })}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Here is the official [demo](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#fixed-header) from material-ui docs.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this if the height of the TableContainer is not known, yet you want the table to stretch to match the height of TableContainer's parent?

Answer (score 7):

Had to pull the table head out from the main table to allow the body to scroll, but here's what I ended up doing. Some CSS was necessary to make the body scrollable.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8kw39m1278

Comment: It's almost there Stephen. Can you ensure that all columns are justified left with the column headers? The second column in your answer is justified right. This better demonstrates the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/ly8vvm5o19

Answer (score 0):

I've made the table scrollable by setting the `max-height` for it's parent div, but for the fixed table header it depends on your columns and the styling has issues with the material-ui i haven't checked more but you can further investigate that here:

Fixed headers: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu, http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/sample-fixed-thead/index.htm

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x92qwnko